# push_back new element to vector

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I have this vector:

```
std::vector<my_class> my_vector;
```

I want to add  new item with the default constructor. So, I write:

```
my_vector.push_back(my_class());
```

is there  way to do it without mention the type directly?. For example something like:

```
 my_vector.push_back(auto()); // imaginary code
```

Comment: There are ways, but the way you have (with explicitly using `my_class()`) is the most readable and therefore most maintainable.

Comment: my_class was an example.. the real one is std::pair<std::vector<std::vector<size_t>>, std::vector<std::vector<size_t>>>()
  So I was afraid of readability after adding this long

Comment: Another alternative just for completeness sake is `my_vector.resize(my_vector.size() + 1)`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`std::vector` has a member function called [`emplace_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) which constructs a new instance of the vector's element type in the vector, from the arguments provided to the function.

So if `my_class` is default constructible, you can do:

```
my_vector.emplace_back();
```

Answer (score 2):

`my_vector.resize(my_vector.size() + 1);`

Answer (score 2):

If your class allows a default constructor:

```
my_vector.push_back({});
```

Comment: It doesn't need an initialization list constructor. It just needs a default constructor (and support for C++11 of course).

Answer (score 1):

```
my_vector.push_back(decltype(my_vector)::value_type());
```

Answer (score 1):

`my_vector.push_back({});`

or even better

`my_vector.emplace_back();`